# Reload data of charts from a Google Chart

Tags: javascript, html, json, charts, google-visualization

I have this code and actually it works fine, except for a thing, when I erase some data on datos.json, or add something new, the chart doesn't refresh the data, although, if i remove the datos.json, it already show me old data and i don't know where it is getting that info ¿?¿?¿?¿?? **ONLY if I do on server "$ service httpd restart" it reload correctly the data**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <!-- Included Jquery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["bar"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            $.getJSON("datos.json", function(response){
                var datos_end  = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response.data);
                var datos_end2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response.data2);

                var options = {
                        width: 900,
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Datos de los sensores',
                        subtitle: 'CO2,CO,VOC,PM2.5'
                    },
                    series: {
                        0: { axis: 'co2'},
                        1: { axis: 'co'},
                        2: { axis: 'voc'},
                        3: { axis: 'pm2'}

                    },
                    axes: {
                        y: {
                                co2: {label: 'ppm'},
                                co: {label: 'ppm'},
                                voc: {side: 'right', label: 'ppb'},
                                pm2: {side: 'left', label: 'ppm'}
                        }
                    }
                };
                var options2 = {
                                width: 900,
                                        chart: {
                                                title: 'Datos sensores 2',
                                                subtitle: 'Temperatura y humedad a la izq., presion a laderecha'
                                },
                                        series: {
                                0: { axis: 'temperatura' },
                                1: { axis: 'presion' },
                                2: { axis: 'humedad'}
                                    },
                                    axes: {
                            y: {
                                  temperatura: {label: 'grados centigrados'}, 
                              presion: {side: 'right', label: 'bar'},
                              humedad: {side: 'left', label: '%'}
                                }
                            }
                            };


            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('div1'));
                            var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('div2'));

            chart.draw(datos_end, options);
            chart2.draw(datos_end2, options2);
        })
        .success(function() { 
            console.log("success");
        })
        .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
            console.log("error " + textStatus);
            console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);})
        .complete(function() {
            console.log("success");
        });
    }
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick='location.reload(true)'>REFRESH DATA</button>
        <p>
    <div id="div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </p>
    <p>
    <div id="div2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I saw this on another post: [Redraw Google Chart after every Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840178/redraw-google-chart-after-every-ajax-call) and i try to do the same without any result :( can anyone help me¿?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"</script>
    <!-- Included Jquery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["bar"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(getData);

        function getData() {
            $.getJSON("datos.json", function(response){
                dwarChart(response.data, response.data2);
            })
            .success(function() { 
                console.log("success");
            })
            .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                console.log("error " + textStatus);
                console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);})
            .complete(function() {
                console.log("success");
            });
        }


        function drawChart(data1, data2) {
            var datos_end  = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data1);
            var datos_end2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data2);


            var options = {
                    width: 900,
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Datos de los sensores',
                        subtitle: 'CO2,CO,VOC,PM2.5'
                    },
                    series: {
                        0: { axis: 'co2'},
                        1: { axis: 'co'},
                        2: { axis: 'voc'},
                        3: { axis: 'pm2'}

                    },
                    axes: {
                        y: {
                            co2: {label: 'ppm'},
                            co: {label: 'ppm'},
                            voc: {side: 'right', label: 'ppb'},
                            pm2: {side: 'left', label: 'ppm'}
                        }
                    }
            };
            var options2 = {
                    width: 900,
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Datos sensores 2',
                        subtitle: 'Temperatura y humedad a la izq., presion a la derecha'
                    },
                    series: {
                        0: { axis: 'temperatura' },
                        1: { axis: 'presion' },
                        2: { axis: 'humedad'}
                    },
                    axes: {
                        y: {
                          temperatura: {label: 'grados centigrados'}, 
                          presion: {side: 'right', label: 'bar'}, 
                          humedad: {side: 'left', label: '%'}
                        }
                    }
            };


            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('div1'));
            var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('div2'));

             chart.draw(data1, options);
             chart2.draw(data2, options2);
        }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick='location.reload(true)'>REFRESH DATA</button>
    <p>
    <div id="div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </p>
    <p>
    <div id="div2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like browser caching.  Try adding a random query string to the request perhaps? Some people at the date/time to the request to make it unique every time.  What have you tried already?

Comment: I try using diferent browser, removing from server datos.json, adding new data, and reboot http deamon, the only things that works is rebooting httpd, but only when new data add, if data erase it always appear.

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Fiddler or Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the traffic between the browser and the server?  That would tell you if the browser is caching your data.

Comment: Not, I'm going to try it, i coment later! :D

Comment: @Balrog30 it is taking from cache this: css data from google chart and font style...