# How To Refresh Google Chart When updating jqGrid

Tags: c#, jqgrid, google-visualization

I have a jqGrid in a user control which is placed on an .aspx page.  I also have a Google Graph to display the grid data on the same page.  Both the grid and chart use Handler1.aspx as the url.  Handler1.ashx makes a call to a SQL server and returns JSON.

When initially loading the page, I can see both the graph and the chart go into Handler1.ashx to get the data - so I get a grid and a nice line chart.

The issue is when I update data in the grid, the chart is not updated.

I have tried the SO solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840178/redraw-google-chart-after-every-ajax-call) without success.  I have also tried a button on the page that calls drawChart().  Here is my grid:

```
        $(function () {
        $('#dataGrid').jqGrid({
            url: 'Handler1.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',

            colNames: ["Days", "Origin IB Loads", "Origin OB Loads", "Dest IB Loads", "Dest IB Loads", "ID"],
            colModel: [
                       { name: 'Days', index: 'Days', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                       { name: 'OrigIB', index: 'OrigIB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                       { name: 'OrigOB', index: 'OrigOB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                       { name: 'DestIB', index: 'DestIB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                       { name: 'DestOB', index: 'DestOB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                       { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 80, Key: true, hidden: true }
                      ],
            loadonce: false,
            pager: '#pagingGrid',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 'All'],
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                $(".ui-pg-selbox option[value='All']").val(10000);
            },
            caption: 'Graph Data',
            editurl: 'Handler2.ashx'
        });

        jQuery("#dataGrid").navGrid("#pagingGrid", {
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: true,
            search: false,
            //searchtext: "Search",
            refresh: true
        },
            {
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: true
            },
            {
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: true
            },
            {
                reloadAfterSubmit: true
            });

    })
```

And here is my Chart - including the grid user control and chart div:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "handler1.ashx",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "false",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('number', 'Days');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Origin IB Loads');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Origin OB Loads');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Dest IB Loads');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Dest OB Loads');
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([jsonData[i].Days, jsonData[i].OrigIB, jsonData[i].OrigOB, jsonData[i].DestIB, jsonData[i].DestOB]);
            }

            var options = {
                title: 'Single Lane Route Quote',
                is3D: true,
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                vAxis: { title: "Days" },
                hAxis: { title: "Loads" }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });

}


<My:GridControl ID ="gridControl" runat="server" />

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>
```

[image]

How can I get the chart to refresh after making an update in the grid?

Comment: are you making two calls to `'Handler1.ashx'`? -- one for the grid and one for the chart? when is the grid loaded?

Comment: @WhiteHat  Yes.  I am making 2 calls to Handler1.  I can see both calls in Firebug on the initial load, but only one after I make an update in the grid data.  Thje grid id loaded before the chart.

Comment: how do you load the grid? do you use the `addRowData` method? or does it load automatically? we could combine the two so you only have to call it once...

Comment: @WhiteHat - the jqGrid is loaded via an ajax call to the same url - handler1.ashx.  See the code snip above the code for the chart.  Just a basic jqGrid.  I can edit my question to show the entire source if it would help.  It would be great if I could populate the chart at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you tried something like this...

1. Load Google
2. Load jqGrid
3. Load Chart when `loadComplete` fires on jqGrid

this will allow google to kick things off, then when the grid updates, so will the chart...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: loadDataGrid,
  packages: ['controls', 'table']
});

function loadDataGrid() {
  $('#dataGrid').jqGrid({
      url: 'Handler1.ashx',
      datatype: 'json',
      mtype: 'POST',
      colNames: ["Days", "Origin IB Loads", "Origin OB Loads", "Dest IB Loads", "Dest IB Loads", "ID"],
      colModel: [
                 { name: 'Days', index: 'Days', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                 { name: 'OrigIB', index: 'OrigIB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                 { name: 'OrigOB', index: 'OrigOB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                 { name: 'DestIB', index: 'DestIB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                 { name: 'DestOB', index: 'DestOB', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, },
                 { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 80, Key: true, hidden: true }
                ],
      loadonce: false,
      pager: '#pagingGrid',
      rowNum: 10,
      rowList: [10, 20, 30, 'All'],
      viewrecords: true,
      gridview: true,
      autoencode: true,
      loadComplete: function (data) {
          $(".ui-pg-selbox option[value='All']").val(10000);

          var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          chartData.addColumn('number', 'Days');
          chartData.addColumn('number', 'Origin IB Loads');
          chartData.addColumn('number', 'Origin OB Loads');
          chartData.addColumn('number', 'Dest IB Loads');
          chartData.addColumn('number', 'Dest OB Loads');
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              chartData.addRow([data[i].Days, data[i].OrigIB, data[i].OrigOB, data[i].DestIB, data[i].DestOB]);
          }

          var options = {
              title: 'Single Lane Route Quote',
              is3D: true,
              curveType: 'function',
              legend: { position: 'bottom' },
              vAxis: { title: "Days" },
              hAxis: { title: "Loads" }
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
          chart.draw(chartData, options);
        }

      },
      caption: 'Graph Data',
      editurl: 'Handler2.ashx'
  });

  jQuery("#dataGrid").navGrid("#pagingGrid", {
      edit: true,
      add: true,
      del: true,
      search: false,
      //searchtext: "Search",
      refresh: true
  },
  {
      closeAfterEdit: true,
      reloadAfterSubmit: true
  },
  {
      closeAfterAdd: true,
      reloadAfterSubmit: true
  },
  {
      reloadAfterSubmit: true
  });
}
```

Comment: I had to use google.charts.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': loadDataGrid }); because I was getting object errors on the chart type, but now the graph changes when the grid is updated!  Thank you very much!